# Classes and functions in Python

Tags: python

While writing some code on classes and functions,I took the case of a function and a class with the same name

code executed as:

```
$python test.py
```

To do that I attempted two scenarios:

1. I first wrote them in one file test.py and got that the function gets called rather than the class

   ```
   class ABC:
       def __init__(self):
           a=3
           print a

   def ABC():
       b=7
       print b

   if __name__=='__main__':
       ABC()
   ```

   output:

   ```
   7
   ```
2. I wrote the function in one file test.py and class of the same name in another file and imported it.when I did not write the `__init__` function, both the function as well as the class got executed, while when I wrote the `__init__` function, only the function got executed

   - without `__init__` function

     1. hello.py:

        ```
        class DEF:
            a=2136
            print a
        ```
     2. test.py:

        ```
        from hello import DEF

            def DEF():
                b=7
                print b

        if __name__=='__main__':
            DEF()
        ```

     output:

     ```
     2136                                                       
     7
     ```
   - with `__init__` function defined

     1. hello.py:

        ```
        class DEF:
            def __init__(self):
            a=2136
            print a
        ```
     2. test.py

        ```
        from hello import DEF 
        def DEF():
            b=7
            print b
        if __name__=='main':
            DEF()
        ```

     output:

     ```
     7
     ```

Comment: Because I read your "Question" but not only I cant identify your doubt, I can't even see a single "?"

Comment: @Meoiswa the question is "Why?" as in "Why is this happening?", not as in "Why do you ask what is the question?" (I guess :) )

Comment: Ah, I see, that was stupid of me. Yeah Martijn Pieters answered your question gracefully then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The body of a class is executed when the class is defined. Thus, the following *always* prints `2136` when python loads the file:

```
class DEF:
    a=2136
    print a
```

Python has to create a class definition named `DEF`, and to do that it executes the body of the class as if it were a function. The local names from that function then form the class body.

This happens regardless of you then replacing the name with another function. It is also run only *once*; if a module has been imported before the top-level code is not executed again.

Comment: thanks Martjin,that was useful..

Answer (score 0):

If your question happens to be why `print a` is executed, python is a parsing language, that means that the class definition code is executed, therefore any functions are called when written there. `print a` is not being called when you call `DEF()` but actually when the interpreter first parses the script.

Comment: You can test this by adding a `return` call in your class definition. Your code will stop executing because it does the `return` while parsing the `DEF` deffinition